# Semantic UI search not populating with AJAX data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, semantic-ui

I have the following AJAX request

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Control/Search/genre.php",
        async: true,
        success: function(text) {
            content = JSON.parse(text);
            console.log(content);
            $('.ui.search')
              .search({
                  source: content,
                  searchFields   : [
                      'genre'
                  ],
              })
            ;
        }
    });
```

According to the documentation here http://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/usage `source: content` should expect content to be an array containing arrays or an array containing objects.

My AJAX repsonse is as follows:

`[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]`

The issue I'm having is that my search field

```
<div class="ui search">
    <input name="genre" class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Genre">
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

Isn't being populated by any pre-determined results as the docs promise.

Perhaps there's something wrong with my `content`?

Comment: Have you checked the console to see if the request is successful? I would also suggest returning JSON from the response instead of text so you can remove the needless `JSON.parse()` call.

Comment: Yes, the array of objects above is the response logged out.

Comment: What is the structure of each object in that array?

Comment: I sorted it now J3Y; it was trying to load the search function towards DOM that didn't exist yet.

Comment: Buddy have you found any solution to your problem ?. I am facing the same issue with my autocomplete which is not working on mobile.